# Delete Excel record when value ends with plus sign ('+')

Tags: excel, vba

We have a blank workbook which I would like the user to be able to paste a list of reference numbers into column A. Some of these reference numbers will have a "+" at the end.

```
Sub texter1()
    With Sheets("texter")
    ll = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For i = 1 To ll
      If InStr(1, .Range("a" & i).Value, "+", 1) Then
        .Range("b" & i).Formula = "=LEFT(A" & i & ", LEN(A" & i & ")-1)"
        .Range("c" & i).Value = Sheets("texter").Range("b" & i).Value
        .Range("d" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($c" & i & ", _
            [Current_Master.xlsm]Master!$A$3:$BB$20000,14,FALSE)"
        .Range("e" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($c" & i & ", _
            [Current_Master.xlsm]Master!$A$3:$BB$20000,15,FALSE)"
      Else
        Cells(i, "a").EntireRow.Delete
      End If
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like reference numbers without the "+" to have the whole row deleted. Reference numbers with a "+" work fine.

this seems to work but has to be run multiple times for it to delete all the rows without a "+" and I cannot figure out why. Please help

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest that `ll` is a confusing name for a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a row inside a loop as far as affects the iterations. Imagine this: you have 4 rows; the second row meets the conditions and is deleted; in the next iteration the counter is 3 but the row number 3 is now the fourth row (when you delete a row, all the ones below go up one position); consequently, row number 3 wouldn't be analysed. Thus the solution is simple:

```
Cells(i, "a").EntireRow.Clear()
```

If you want to actually delete the whole row, you would have to do it outside the main loop. For example: store all the rows to be deleted in an array and iterate through this array right after completing the main loop.

Another alternative would be performing the iterations in the main loop in inverse order (from maximum row to minimum one), although this option is not always applicable (not sure if in your case) and might provoke further problems. The two options above are good enough, I have mentioned this last alternative just as something worthy to be known.

--- UPDATE

To delete the rows after the main loop you can use something on these lines:

```
'Declaration of variables
ReDim allRows(ll + 1) As Long
Dim allRowsCount As Long: allRowsCount = 0
```

In your main loop you store the given rows (where you have now `Cells(i, "a").EntireRow.Delete`):

```
For i = 1 To ll
'etc.

else
    allRowsCount = allRowsCount + 1
    allRows(allRowsCount) = i
```

After the loop is completed, you go through all the stored rows (in inverse order) and delete them:

```
If (allRowsCount > 0) Then

    Dim curRow As Long: curRow = allRowsCount + 1

    Do
        curRow = curRow - 1
        .Rows(allRows(curRow)).Delete
    Loop While (curRow > 1)

End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sence, but I wouldn't know how to implement your solution. Would i add the row numbers to a variable? Apologies for my ignorance. or could I not add an adjustment to the lastrow variable within the loop? (ie; ll = ll-1)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. But now seems to constantly loop I have to break the code manually.

Comment: @user2653758 I have updated my code with a way to store the rows. But, as said, the suggested Clear() works fine and does not make any real difference with Delete in most of the cases.

Comment: Thank you for all input. I like the clear method (nice and simple) Is there an easy way to remove the then empty rows?

Comment: @user2653758 you are welcome. If you think that this is the right answer, please select it as such (left hand side, tick).